# Is it possible to add colorbar properties to a maltlab plot?

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I'd really like to know if there's a way to add the colorbar properties we usually find in surface or mesh, but this time for a simple plot.

Thanx you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to add a colorbar to a plot? The [COLORBAR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colorbar.html) function does that, but it's really only useful if you have an object in your plot that uses a [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html), like a [surface](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) or an [image](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html).

For simple line plots, you're probably better off going with a [legend](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html).

Comment: Well actually i'd like to add an intensity, with color, to different part of my plot.

Comment: @clowny: I think you're going to have to add much more detail to your question. I still can't figure out what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what gnovice stated in their answer you can define your own colormap.  I would suggest you model it off of a `HSV` scheme since you're wanting to vary the intensity.  That was you can select the color you want and vary just the intensity value of it.